# Remove table TR while maintaining addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, I have a Table TR that gets removed when you push a button. I am using animate.css and would like to add a class once my ajax request is done. This slides the row out, But then I need the row deleted as well.

My javascript is as follows:

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').html();
    var dataString = 'id='+id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/deleteEvent/",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $(tr).addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
            $(tr).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

The part I am focusing on is:

```
success: function() {
   $(tr).addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
   $(tr).remove();
}
```

Right now, the table row just disappears so It's like it's skipping the add class part to slide the row out. How can I make the add class happen at the same time as the remove?

Comment: It's not skipping the `addClass`, just doing it really quickly and then immediately removing it. You could try adding a pause: `setTimeout(function() { $(tr).remove(); }, 3000);` or using the jQuery [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to transition the sliding out more smoothly.

Comment: That did it. Please put in answer, so I can accept.

Comment: even better `$(tr).addClass('animated bounceOutLeft').delay(3000).remove();`

Comment: @Jaime Agreed, that is better. I had forgotten about `delay`.

Comment: In this case, delay doesn't work as expected. Checkout the following (which uses delay) http://jsfiddle.net/9rbXg/1/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/9rbXg/ (which uses settimeout)

Per the documentation, delay is useful for adding a delay between queued jquery effects, but is not a replacement for settimeout. http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a callback you can use to know when addclass is finished. You might want to try using setTimeout to fire the remove after a small interval.

Something like this:

```
$(tr).addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(tr).remove();
},500);
```

Here's a working fiddle (without all the ajax stuff)
http://jsfiddle.net/9rbXg/